# Center any sized content and still allow scrolling

Tags: html, css

Is there any CSS technique to center an image (or any other element) within container so that:

1. it appears centered horizontally and vertically initially (that is, its center is in the center of the containing div, no matter the size of the content);
2. it can be scrolled if it overflows its containing div.

If the content is always smaller than the container, I can simply use this well-known technique:

```
.content {
     position: relative;
     left: 50%;
     top: 50%;
     transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

This works perfectly for content that 'fits' inside its container, but  stops working when the content starts to overflow.

Or I can remove the `top`, `left` and `transform` and let the content appear in the top-left corner of the container, which is potentially fine for very large content, but looks terrible for smaller content.

So is there a way in CSS to center content and allow scrolling for both overflowing and fit content?

The closest I've come is on this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/4k5vp6m6/3/

I kind of suspect that the only way to do this is to inspect the content after loading to see if it fits or not.

Comment: Flexbox is able to do this, there are probably a few other questions going into detail on how to use flexbox.

Comment: Dang it. I did not find that answer. Thanks @AlexanderO'Mara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox can do that

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/4k5vp6m6/4/)